# nth-child(12) dosen't work, but the rest yes

Tags: html, css

I have a list with 12 elements , within those elements I have a div
What I want to achieve its that every div will have diffrent size
So I use nth-child on the `li` elemnt to set diffrent size to every `div` element
But the 12 one dosen't work, the rest nth-child workt perfectly

My list:

```
<ul class="size">
     <li data-radius="1"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 2px </li>
     <li data-radius="2"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 4px </li>                                    <li data-radius="1"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 2px </li>
     <li data-radius="3"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 6px </li>
     <li data-radius="4"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 8px </li>
     <li data-radius="5"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 10px </li>
     <li data-radius="6"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 12px </li>
     <li data-radius="7"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 14px </li>
     <li data-radius="8"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 16px </li>
     <li data-radius="9"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 18px </li>
     <li data-radius="10"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 20px </li>
     <li data-radius="11"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 22px </li>
     <li data-radius="12"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 24px </li>
</ul>
```

My css:

```
.circleSize {
      background-color:black;
      display:inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      border-radius: 50%;
}
.size li:nth-child(1) .circleSize {
      width:2px;
      height:2px;
}
.size li:nth-child(2) .circleSize {
      width:4px;
      height:4px;
}
.size li:nth-child(3) .circleSize {
      width:6px;
      height:6px;
}
.size li:nth-child(4) .circleSize {
      width:8px;
      height:8px;
            }
.size li:nth-child(5) .circleSize {
      width:10px;
      height:10px;
}
.size li:nth-child(6) .circleSize {
      width:12px;
      height:12px;
}
.size li:nth-child(7) .circleSize {
      width:14px;
      height:14px;
}
.size li:nth-child(8) .circleSize {
      width:16px;
      height:16px;
 }
 .size li:nth-child(9) .circleSize {
      width:18px;
      height:18px;
 }
 .size li:nth-child(10) .circleSize {
      width:20px;
      height:20px;
 }
 .size li:nth-child(11) .circleSize {
      width:22px;
      height:22px;
 }
.size li:nth-child(12) .circleSize {
      width:24px;
      height:24px;
}
```

My jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4nvug6og/

Comment: you just had a mistake in your fiddle html

Comment: It does work, but you have thirteen `<li>` elements: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4nvug6og/2/

Comment: You have two `data-radius="1"` items.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's about a typo (note to the potential answerers too - *please don't answer off-topic questions*).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, because you have an extra **`<li data-radius="1">`** and in your case **`<li data-radius="12">`** is actually **`nth-child(13)`**.

Try scrolling to the right and removing that extra **`li`** and all will be fine.

**Working snippet:**

```css
.circleSize {
      background-color:black;
      display:inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      border-radius: 50%;
}
.size li:nth-child(1) .circleSize {
      width:2px;
      height:2px;
}
.size li:nth-child(2) .circleSize {
      width:4px;
      height:4px;
}
.size li:nth-child(3) .circleSize {
      width:6px;
      height:6px;
}
.size li:nth-child(4) .circleSize {
      width:8px;
      height:8px;
            }
.size li:nth-child(5) .circleSize {
      width:10px;
      height:10px;
}
.size li:nth-child(6) .circleSize {
      width:12px;
      height:12px;
}
.size li:nth-child(7) .circleSize {
      width:14px;
      height:14px;
}
.size li:nth-child(8) .circleSize {
      width:16px;
      height:16px;
 }
 .size li:nth-child(9) .circleSize {
      width:18px;
      height:18px;
 }
 .size li:nth-child(10) .circleSize {
      width:20px;
      height:20px;
 }
 .size li:nth-child(11) .circleSize {
      width:22px;
      height:22px;
 }
.size li:nth-child(12) .circleSize {
      width:24px;
      height:24px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="size">
     <li data-radius="1"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 2px </li>
     <li data-radius="2"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 4px </li>
     <li data-radius="3"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 6px </li>
     <li data-radius="4"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 8px </li>
     <li data-radius="5"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 10px </li>
     <li data-radius="6"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 12px </li>
     <li data-radius="7"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 14px </li>
     <li data-radius="8"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 16px </li>
     <li data-radius="9"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 18px </li>
     <li data-radius="10"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 20px </li>
     <li data-radius="11"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 22px </li>
     <li data-radius="12"><div class="circleSize"></div> <br /> 24px </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, the question is off-topic. You're not supposed to answer off-topic questions.

Comment: If the question is off-topic, flag it @nicael.

Comment: But voting / flagging for closure doesn't mean you can go and answer it afterwards.